# Android. ListView. Transition to fragment in activity2 from activity1

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity, android-fragments

There is an activity and it has a list (listview). I need to adjust the click handler so that when you click on the first item calls Activity2 showing the first fragment, and if you click on the second element, then bring Activity2 showing the second fragment.

[image: desired behavior description]

My code Activity1:

```
public class Class extends Activity {
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;
View emptyView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
    getActionBar().hide();
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    listView.setEmptyView(
            emptyView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.empty_view, null));
    ((ViewGroup)listView.getParent()).addView(emptyView);
    fillListView();
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
           if (((TextView) view).getText() == "Go1"){

           } else
           if (((TextView) view).getText() == "Go2"){

             /*  FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getFragmentManager();
               FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = fragmentManager1
                       .beginTransaction();
               Intent Fragment1 = new Intent(Class.this, MainActivity.class);
               startActivity(Fragment1);
               Fr myFragment1 = new Fr();
               myFragment1.setRetainInstance(true);
               fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.container, myFragment1);
               fragmentTransaction1.commit();
               SearchActivity.this.finish();*/
           }
            if (((TextView) view).getText() == "Go3"){

            }
        }
    });

    EditText editFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_search);
    editFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }
    });

}

private void fillListView() {
    List<String> catList = new ArrayList<String>();
    catList.add("Go1");
    catList.add("Go2");
    catList.add("Go3");

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, catList);
}
```

My code Activity2:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
    selectItem(i);

    }
}


private void selectItem(int i) {
    String str = toString().trim();
    switch(i){

        case 1:

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction();
            Quadrat myFragment = new Quadrat();
            myFragment.setRetainInstance(true);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, myFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            break;
        case 2:

            FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = fragmentManager1
                    .beginTransaction();
            Qoob myFragment1 = new Qoob();
            myFragment1.setRetainInstance(true);
            fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.container, myFragment1);
            fragmentTransaction1.commit();

            break;

        default:;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well what is the question exactly? Wiht what do you have a problem? Do you know how to start an activity using an intent? In the onclick handler you better do something like if ( position == 0) {start activity2 with fragment1} else if ( position == 1 ) {start activity2 with fragment2}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         Intent Fragment1 = new Intent(Class.this, MainActivity.class);
           startActivity(Fragment1);
```

You can indicate that activity which fragment to use at startup. Add a parameter to the intent;

```
       int fragmentnr = position;

       Intent intent = new Intent(Class.this, MainActivity.class);
       intent.putExtra("fagmentnr", fragmentnr ); 
       startActivity(intent);
```

Then in onCreate of MainActivity (MainActivity? Not Activity2?) you have to determine fragmentnr first;

These puExtra()'s with a key work the same as using parameters for functions.

Comment: Yes. MainActivity is Activity2. But it don't work for me. "int fragmentnr = position;" in Activity1?

Comment: Place my code in onItemClick() (where else) and remove all other code from it.

Comment: I'm still new and do not quite understand what was happening. We have introduced a variable fragmentnr And then what? how to initialize activity2?

Comment: I showed you how to start activity 2. But you did not place my code in onItemClick function yet. Please do here. And test.

Answer (score 0):

I'll just leave this here
Activity1:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            if (((TextView) view).getText() == "Go1"){
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("key", 0);
                startActivity(in);

            }
            if (((TextView) view).getText() == "Go2"){
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("key", 1);
                startActivity(in);

            }
            if (((TextView) view).getText() == "Go3"){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Go3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

MainActivity or Activity2:

```
if (getIntent().getIntExtra("key", 0) == 0){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager1 = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction1 = fragmentManager1
                .beginTransaction();
        Quadrat myFragment1 = new Quadrat();
        myFragment1.setRetainInstance(true);
        fragmentTransaction1.replace(R.id.container, myFragment1);
        fragmentTransaction1.commit();
    }
```

Code MainActivity write in method onCreate